# Why is using eval necessary to pass quoted arguments

Tags: shell, quoting, eval

I have the following example.

```
#!/bin/bash
ARGUMENTS="-executors 1 -description \"The Host\" "

# call1
# error: parameter Host" is not allowed
java -jar swarm-client.jar $ARGUMENTS

# call2    
# works fine with eval
eval java -jar swarm-client.jar $ARGUMENTS
```

In `$ARGUMENTS`, I have a quoted argument.  I do not understand why grouping of argument by escaped quotes is not working in `call1`.  I do not understand why is `eval` necessary to resolve the quoting problem.

I think I do not understand the process and the order of command evaluation in shell. Can you explain it to me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't *pass quoted arguments* to  a command, you pass arguments.

When you enter:

```
cmd arg1 arg2
```

The shell parses that line in its own syntax where space is a word delimiter and calls `cmd1` with `cmd`, `arg1` and `arg2` as arguments.

**Note**: `cmd` does not receive any space character in its arguments, the spaces are just operators in the shell language syntax.

Like when in C, you write `func("foo", "bar")`, at run time, `func` receives two pointer arguments, it does not see any of the `(` or `,` or `"` or space character.

Also part of the shell syntax is quoting. `"` is used to be able to have words that contain characters that are otherwise part of the shell syntax.

When you do:

```
cmd "arg 1" arg2
```

`cmd` receives `cmd`, `arg 1` and `arg2` as arguments. It does not see any `"` character. Those `"` are used to prevent the space from being treated as a word separator in the shell syntax.

Now, when you do:

```
cmd $VAR
```

it's not the same as doing:

```
cmd the content of the variable
```

If it were, you'd have trouble with:

```
VAR='foo; reboot'
echo $VAR
```

for instance.

In Bourne-like shell, the content of `$VAR` is not passed verbatim as a single argument to `cmd` either (unfortunately; it's been fixed in some other  shells like `rc`, `es`, `fish` and to a lesser extent `zsh`). Instead, it's subject to splitting and globbing (`split+glob`) and the resulting words passed to `cmd`.

The splitting is done based on the characters in the special `$IFS` variable, by default space, tab and newline.

For your `$ARGUMENTS` which contains `-executors 1 -description "The Host"`, that's splitting into `-executors`, `1`, `-description`, `"The` and `Host"`. Since none of those words contain wildcard character, the glob part doesn't apply, so it's those words that are passed to `cmd`.

Here, you could use the `split+glob` operator, and use as separator for the splitting part a character that does not appear in those words:

```
ARGUMENTS='-executors|1|-description|The Host'
IFS='|'
cmd $ARGUMENTS
```

Or better, for shells that support them (like `bash`), [use arrays](/a/416578), where you can have a variable that contains all those arguments.

`eval` is to evaluate shell code. So the other option is to have `ARGUMENTS` contain shell code (text in the shell syntax as opposed to a list of arguments), and have that passed to `eval` for interpretation. But  remember to quote the variable to avoid the split+glob operator:

```
eval "cmd $ARGUMENTS"
```

Answer (score 7):

When a quote is inside another string, bash treats it as just another character.  Use arrays instead:

```
args=(-executors 1 -description "The Host")
java -jar swarm-client.jar "${args[@]}"
```

For a good discussion of this issue, see ["I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Also, use lower-case or mixed-case names for your variables.  The system uses all capitals for its variable names and you don't want to accidentally overwrite one of them.

#### How it works

When the array `args` is defined, separate quoted strings become separate items in the array.  We can see this by using `declare -p arrayname` to examine what is in the array:

```
$ args=(-executors 1 -description "The Host")
$ declare -p args
declare -a args=([0]="-executors" [1]="1" [2]="-description" [3]="The Host")
```

As we can see, the string `The Host` is element 3 in the array.

When bash expands the special form `"${args[@]}"`, each element of the array becomes a separate *word*.  In this way, the string `The Host` remains one *word* even though it contains spaces.

Comment: Thnx for the solution with the array - it seems clearer than using eval. Still I do not understand how the evaluation of items in array happens, when the "${args[@]}" is expanded. What is evaluated different, when I use array expansion instead of strings. Any tips on the literature to learn that?